# .NET language pack for data annotation in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I wanted to change the language of the errors thrown by the validation/data annotation, I manage to do that, by adding the following method to the global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
}
```

At the beginning that wouldn't change anything, then I realized I had to install the .NET italian language pack.
After I did that it works fine, the problem is that the language only works on my PC where the package is installed and not on other pcs that run the exact same application. So my question is, how do I import the language pack into the application?

Comment: I am not sure, but it might be something to the reference properties. I once had to change "Copy Local" to true because the reference files were not being built to the server

Comment: I assume you're talking default behavior and not when you use a local resource for DataAnnotations. Would that be accurate?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the default one. But i don't mind using a local resource if this fixes the problem..

Comment: @Sophie Did you figure out how to do it ?

Comment: If you want language packs to be added to Azure Web Apps, please vote for this request : http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/9854277-provide-net-language-packs-on-web-apps

Comment: @bob I went for the easy solution.. I just added custom message for the annotation..